# Having one column dependent on the order of another column in Amazon QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, visualization, amazon-quicksight

Here is the simple table data I have:

[image]

What I want:

For each business, I am only interested in it's **LATEST** Profit% in QuickSight table format (or any other visual type honestly and not just table)

What I have tried:

I put this table into QuickSight's Table visual type and put the "Business Name" into "Group by", "Timestamp" and "Profit%" into "Value". Fortunately, I can select only the max value of the Timestamp column (which is exactly what I want!) as you can see in the image below:

[image]

The first two columns are exactly what I want however if you look at the "Profit%" column, you can see that I am getting a "Sum" value. But I just want the respective value associated with that respective "Max" Timestamp only! For example for the "Business-1" row, the expected value in the Profit% column is 25.

Possible solutions I have tried:

i. Using a calculated field using the [lastValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/lastValue-function.html) function - Unfortunately, this function is not supported in the region I am using QuickSight. If it was supported, my issue would have been resolved.

ii. Using a calculated field called rank using the function [rank](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/rank-function.html) and then using a filter for this column. This has not worked out as yet. Suggestions are welcome if it is actually possible using this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will be able to get the desired result by using the maxover function and an ifelse function
ifelse(Timestamp=maxover(Timestamp,[{Business Name}],PRE_FILTER),{Profit%},0)
[image]